# Счетчик (таймер) на каждый товар - Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wp-plugin

Недавно увидел на одном из сайтов интересное решение, на каждый товар был установлен счетчик (таймер) после окончания которого товар становится доступным к покупке. Для полной ясности добавляю скриншот.[image: таймер на каждый товар]

Может у кого-то есть идеи по реализации данной функции или может кто знает уже готовые решения? Спасибо зарание!

Comment: весь код за вас можно написать?

Comment: Для каждого товара заведите поле "Начало продаж", в которое заносите дату и время, когда товар станет доступен для продажи. На странице товара сравнивайте с текущими значениями даты и времени и добавляйте таймер обратного отсчета, если он нужен.